# Subdomain Masking, redirection already provided

Tags: subdomain, masking

I'm using a server which allows me to create and redirect subdomains. However, it is reflected on the address URL bar.

What I want is to keep `subdomain.domain.com` as base URL for the subdirectories inside `domain.com/subdirectory/`

Searching on the internet I always come up with these lines for .htaccess, which I think it does the redirection, but not the masking.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/$1 [L]
```

**edit**

Tried this, but didn't work

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    /subdirectory/
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$  http://subdomain.domain.com/$1  [P]
ProxyPassReverse /subdirectory/ http://subdomain.domain.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is solved using mod_proxy with mod_redirect. Research this Apache documentation page: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html

I do warn you that you have to be careful when configuring your Apache to mod_proxy. Here is the Apache documentation on that. There is a strong warning on the top of the page. But do not let that scare you. Just be careful and thorough.

Having said that, I used to use this feature *A LOT!* If configured safely, it works extremely well, is seamless, and highly reliable.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub [NC]
RewriteRule .* sub.domain.com [P,L]
```

You do not need RewriteBase unless it is something other than the default.

I think this example will work for you. If not, I will change the example and we will try again. To test, use [R,L] instead of [P,L].

Comment: Ok, but my `subdomain` points to a `subdirectory` inside my local `public_html`. Is it the same?

Comment: Exactly the same. Instead of R (redirect) you use P (proxy). You are not using R for redirect in your example above. It really should be [R,L]. I think that is okay because redirect is assumed. However, in the new case, you would replace the R with P to proxy instead of redirect [P,L]. It is a *slick as snot* option if mod_proxy is configured to be safe.

Comment: But I need to proxy the folder to -> the subdomain, not the subdomain to the folder. I think that the example above is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Oh yeah! I messed that. Sorry. Hold on. I will update the answer with an example that might work better.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I've edited my question with another try

Comment: I updated the answer. Great fingers type alike!

Comment: I'll try it now! Should I have to deactivate the redirection in my server settings?

Comment: I fixed the escapes in the example... Oooopppssss.

Comment: Ok, so we don't need to escape dots inside RewriteRule?

Comment: No. It is not a regular expression- it is a URL.

Comment: I should mention that the configuration in my Server Panel can be: simple add a subdomain, or add a subdomain + redirection (but no masking). Which should I set?

Comment: Simple sub-domain. The redirection I think refers to adding a 301 redirect. BTW- I do not know what you are using to configure your site. I assume a control panel. I know VirtualMin, but not cPanel or any of the others.

Comment: I've tried **without** redirection from the server panel, first with [R,L] and then with [P,L], however it tells "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Comment: Odd. Can you access the sub.domain.tld directly in a browser? It may be possible that there is a configuration problem with the sub-domain including likely a file level permissions/site ownership issue.

Comment: Regarding the image, you are adding a redirection- but I am not sure I understand this screen as much as I should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15319/discussion-between-redraw-and-closetnoc).

Comment: Going there now...

Comment: I just thought of something. If you cannot get the proxy thing to work, perhaps you can redeploy your application within the sub-domain directory and make it work there. Just a thought.

Comment: I'm not sure about understood very well. I also thought that RewriteRule could be something like this `RewriteRule ^/subfolder/(.*)$ http://sub.mydomain.com/$1`

Comment: Yes, but that example is backwards from what we were doing and does not cover all bases such as sub-domain.domain.tld and www.sub-domain.domain.tld. It does not necessarily make it transparent either. But like I said, you can remove the redirect we did yesterday and deploy the application in the sub-domain directory that we found making the redirect unnecessary.

Comment: I understood. I'll try installing my application in that sub-domain folder created by the hosting server.

Comment: It worked. Finally. Still wonder why I couldn't make a proxy redirection from the sub-domain folder to the real folder, but it doesn't matter now. This server's configuration might not be very common, or maybe it is on shared hosting. Huge thanks closetnoc!

Comment: Anytime my friend! It was a pleasure. I am glad it is doing what you want now.